Block HTTP/HTTPS POST/PUT from a container
Is there a practical way to inspect HTTP/HTTPS and block arbitrary POST and PUT requests, from within a container, to the internet? (while still allowing GET requests)
I had a look at eBPF but I am not sure how to properly set it up, nor if that is the right tool for this.
Thank you.

The common way would be a proxy server.

Thanks @vidarlo
Do you know a small proxy server that has this capability with HTTPS? and perhaps can also be run on docker alongside the other containers?

We generally don't do product recommendations. My goto would be squid, because I know it, but I believe both Apache and Nginx would be equally valid choices.

Thanks a lot for the quick reply. I was having a look on squid, and nginx as well.
I am not super familiar with neither configs but I will give it a try, I guess I just need something like 'http_access deny POST' on squid?
I'll be amazing if that works :) then I just need to make sure the containers can only do tcp through the proxy...

well, this will still need a ssl-bump and self-signed certs (which will have to be accepted by the client), right?

If you want to inspect TLS secured traffic you will always need a way to access the content, regardless of what software you use. That generally implies a certificate trusted by the client.
